# Conjecture about Jordan curve and filled Julia sets?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fractals, complex-dynamics

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function and let $J(f)$ be the boundary of the filled Julia set of $f$.

Conjecture

If $J(f)$ is an analytic Jordan curve then $f(z) = g.inv( g(z)^n )$ where $n$ is a positive integer , $g.inv$ is the (functional) inverse of $g$ and $g$ or $g.inv$ are entire.

Example : $ f(z) = z^2 , J(f) $ is the unit circle.

Comment: What is the filled Julia set of an *entire* function?

Comment: Filled Julia set or connected Julia set is the same. An entire function is a function that has a taylor series with infinite radius. Wiki it. Are you the downvoter If I may ask ?

Comment: The Julia set of an entire function is, by definition, the set of points in the complex plane for which the set of iterates of the function form a normal family of functions at that point. In the polynomial case, it makes sense to define the *filled Julia set* to be the set of points that remain bounded under iteration of the function. It can then be proved that the boundary of the filled Julia set is the Julia set of the polynomial. There is no such equivalent characterization for entire functions. I believe your question is trivial in the polynomial case and ill-defined in the entire case. I

Comment: That sounds intresting but What do you mean by the boundary of the filled julia is the Julia set ? That every point inside ends up in a fixed point ?? Even so , I talked about the boundary anyways so I do not see a problem. Are you claiming for polynomials the boundary is not sucked to a fixpoint and for a nonpolynomial Some points on the boundary are ?? Plz clarify. Also a link to proofs about it would be nice. You get a +1 for constructive comment.

Comment: When we iterate a complex polynomial, there is an *escape radius*. Once an iterate is larger in absolute value than that escape radius, we know the orbit will diverge. There is no such escape criterion for transcendental entire functions. For example, $e^z$ is small when $z$ is a large negative number. Thus, it doesn't really make sense to talk about a filled Julia set in that context.

Comment: Robert Devaney calls the Julia set result of iterating complex expontials a "Cantor Bouquets", http://math.bu.edu/people/bob/papers/uab.pdf

Comment: There are several problem with your question:
1. What do you mean an analytic Jordan curve in the complex plane ?
2. The complex dynamic in one dimensional has two separate field: rational map and transcendental map. The word "entire" is not clear for which direction you want to consider.
3. The conjecture you state is not good. Does $g$ satisfies any condition, what does the number $n$ condition? I can take $n=0$ then the conjecture is trivial. 
Last, you can take a look at the section 9.9,Iteration of Rational Functions, Alan Beardon for Jordan Curve argument in the study of Rational map